# empty in Monix Task

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, project-reactor, monix

Project Reactor has something like Mono.empty[T]() which can be handled in special circumstances where you do not have anything when it is evaluated. Is there something similar in Monix Task?

```
def getItemFromList[T](inp: Mono[List[T]]): Mono[T] = {
    val moList = inp.defaultIfEmpty(List[T]())
    moList.flatMap[T]((list: List[T]) => {
      if (list.isEmpty) Mono.empty[T]()
      else Mono.just(list.head)
    })
  }
```

Here I am trying to lift an item from a list of items, where the list can be non existent while reading from the db. I do not want to send something like Mono.just(List()) as that will require me to add another empty/null check on the db call side.

Answer (score 0):

Monix' `Task` and Project Reactor's `Mono` differ in terms of logic.
While `Mono` can complete to "nothing", `Task` can only complete to "something" or never complete at all (which makes a lot more sense).

To correctly describe your problem with `Task`, you will have to use something like `Task[Option[T]]` and then return `Task.now(None)` or move over to Monix' `Observable`, which models a stream of elements (that can also be empty).

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this.